# Improper integrals with bounds 0 to infinity

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{x^{1/2}+x^{3/2}}dx$$

I managed to integrate correctly and get $2\arctan(\sqrt{x})+C$, but I was wondering why my teacher split it up into two pieces, one from $0$ to $1$ with a limit at $0$ evaluating $2\arctan(\sqrt{x})+C$ and the other $1$ to $\infty$ with a limit at infinity evaluating $2\arctan(\sqrt{x})+C$. Can I just take $2\arctan(\sqrt{x})$ and evaluate from $0$ to $\infty$ with a limit at infinity?

Comment: You can do this, but *only* after you've proven that this doubly-improper (double because of the $\infty$ and the singularity at $0$) integral converges in the standard sense. We *define* $\int_0^\infty (\cdots)dx$ to be the sum of $\int_0^c (\cdots)dx$ and $\int_c^\infty (\cdots)dx$ provided the latter integrals exist for some $c$; this is why your teacher is splitting the integral into two.

Comment: You can just evaluate your answer from $0$ to $\infty$. Maybe your teacher just wanted to show that evaluating it from $0$ to $1$ gives you $\pi/2$ and evaluating it from $1$ to $\infty$ also gives you $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Accelerator Yes maybe teacher wanted students to know its $\frac \pi2 + \frac \pi2$ but I wonder is it possible to have first sight intuition for the same by looking at the problem only?

Comment: Sure, you can split up the integral like that, but what would be the point? That is just more work. The integrand is smooth everywhere on $(0,\infty)$, so you can just find the indefinite integral and just plug in the limits. That's the intuition everyone else would have.

Comment: @Accelerator Indeed! The integrand is smooth everywhere on $(0, \infty)$  but what fascinated me is that teacher split the integral as if he/she already knew that $\int_0^1f(x)dx = \int_1^\infty f(x)dx = \frac \pi2$ where $f(x) = \frac 1{x^{\frac 12} + x^{\frac 32}}$

Answer (score 4):

Simpler approach: Let $y=x^\frac{1}{2}$.  Then $dy=\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx$ or $dx=2ydy$.  Integral is $\int_0^\infty 2\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy=\pi$

Answer (score 2):

My best guess  is that it's because we have an improper integral with an issue caused at each boundary point: $0$ and $\infty$ each cause a certain type of improperness. Working entirely based on $(0,\infty)$ can be a bit sketchy, because these improper integrals are defined as limits. Namely: for this type, we can define

$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_a^c f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
+ \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_c^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$$

for any $c \in (0,\infty)$.

> **Note:** You may be thinking of "wait, isn't this just the property of additivity?", where we have
> $$\int_a^b f(x)  \, \mathrm{d} x = \int_a^c f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x + \int_c^b  \, \mathrm{d} x$$
> for a $c \in (a,b)$. While it is **motivated** by that, this is the **definition** for this type of improper integral, the starting point.

Opting to work solely over $(0,\infty)$ without splitting it up *could* work, if you're careful. One has to be mindful that (if $F'=f$)

$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
= \lim_{b \to \infty} F(x) - \lim_{a \to 0^+} F(x)$$

which is basically per that definition anyways. Concerns can certainly arise, however, if we let

$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
= \lim_{t \to \infty} F(t) - F \left( \frac 1 t \right)$$

or any other scheme in which the first summand seems to go to $F$ "at infinity" and the second seems to go to $F$ at $0$. This is useful in the notion of the so-called "[Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)", but sometimes leads to results for integrals that (under normal definitions) don't converge or exist: $1/x$ for instance having an integral of $0$ over $(-1,1)$.

> Put differently, the crux of this latter item being an issue could be thought of as you constraining $F(t)$ and $F(1/t)$ to go somewhere at the same speed and along a certain path, which could affect the limit, whereas the limit in two variables $a,b$ is a bit more free and matches more appropriately the formal definitions of limit.
>
> I bring it up to establish why the initial definition is what we use, contrasted against your own.
>
> Of course, this still may even match the "standard" answer for an integral, as it seems to here, but it's a sort of "right answer for the wrong reasons" sort of deal.

Answer (score 2):

If not wrong: You could solve the problem but you want to know why did your teacher split the above integral as
$$\int_0^\infty = \int_0^1 + \int_1^\infty$$
or as
$$\arctan(x)|_0^\infty = \arctan(x)|_0^1 + \arctan(x)|_1^\infty$$

then [Comment by @Accelerator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Q1N.png)

however, for this particular case

$$\begin{align*}\int_0^\infty \frac {dx}{x^{\frac 12} + x^{\frac 32}}
&=\left(\int_0^1 + \int_1^\infty\right)\frac {1}{x^{\frac 12} + x^{\frac 32}}dx
\\&=\int_0^1 \frac {dx}{x^{\frac 12} + x^{\frac 32}} + \color{blue}{\int_1^\infty\frac {dx}{x^{\frac 12} + x^{\frac 32}}}
; \text{ Let } \color{green}{x = \frac 1y }
\\&=\int_0^1 \frac {dx}{x^{\frac 12} + x^{\frac 32}}  + \int_1^0\frac {\frac{-dy}{y^2}}{y^{\frac {-1}2} + y^{\frac {-3}2}}
\\&=\int_0^1 \frac {dx}{x^{\frac 12} + x^{\frac 32}}  + \color{blue}{\int_0^1 \frac {dy}{y^{\frac 12} + y^{\frac {3}2}}}
\\& = 2\times\int_0^1 \frac {dx}{x^{\frac 12} + x^{\frac 32}}
\\& = 2\times\int_0^1 \frac {x^{-\frac 12}dx}{1 + x}
\\& = 2\frac {\beta\left(\frac 12, \frac 12\right)}{2} = \pi
\end{align*}$$

[Why did I use $\beta$ function?: Master Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELYA3.png)